# Why does the XOR operation of 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 equal to 0?

Tags: python, hash, computer-science

I was attempting a problem where I had to count the even frequencies of numbers in O(1) time. So I defaulted to XOR thinking that given some even counts of numbers it would eventually output 0. This worked for some cases but in other cases e.g. 0 or 1,2,3 it would fail.

For the 0 case this makes sense as 0^0=0 but I'm not sure why 1^2^3 = 0. After some research there's something about hash collisions but I still don't quite understand why the output is 0 for 1^2^3 (using Python).

Is it because everything is an object with a corresponding hash value? Do all data types in all languages have hash values? I might have some fundamental misunderstandings.

Comment: Just write those numbers in binary notation, and perform the XOR ... should be clear?

Comment: What do you think a bitwise XOR does? What do hash collisions have to do with anything?

Comment: Why should it not be zero?

Comment: What answer would you expect?

Comment: Ok, writing it in binary notation it's clear why 1^2^3 is 0. I didn't think about the binary formats. In my head in the int formats 1,2,3 are unique numbers that should lead to a non-0 output, I'm not sure how I would put that to a solution

Comment: Actually, after writing that I guess that's why you would hash the integer values to give some unique hash to then XOR which would give 0 for all even frequencies

Answer (score 3):

For bitwise XOR'ing, a number xor'ed by itself is 0.

```
1^2 = 3

0010
0001
----
0011


3^3 = 0

0011
0011
----
0000
```

Answer (score 2):

`1 ^ 2` is 3, because 1 and 2 specify two separate bits. (That is, XORing 1 with 2 turns on the 2 bit which, when added to the 1 bit that's already on, makes the result 3.) XORing that with 3 turns both those bits off (because the 1 and 2 bits are on in 3) so the result is zero. Another way to understand it is that anything XORed with itself is 0, because the operation turns off the same bits that are already on.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are performing a bitwise XOR comparision and XOR is TRUE if only one bit is TRUE, otherwise FALSE

```py
# 1 = "0001"
# 2 = "0010"
# 3 = "0011"

print(f"0 xor 0 xor 0 = {0 ^ 0 ^ 0}")
print(f"0 xor 1 xor 1 = {0 ^ 1 ^ 1}")
print(f"1 xor 0 xor 1 = {1 ^ 0 ^ 1}")

# 0 xor 0 xor 0 = 0
# 0 xor 1 xor 1 = 0
# 1 xor 0 xor 1 = 0
```